# How to convert sub query to joins?

Tags: mysql, opencart, mariadb

I am using this query in my opencart site

```
SELECT  MIN(tmp.date_added) AS date_start,
        MAX(tmp.date_added) AS date_end,
        COUNT(tmp.order_id) AS `orders`,
        SUM(tmp.products) AS products,
        SUM(tmp.tax) AS tax,
        SUM(tmp.total) AS total
    FROM  
      ( SELECT  o.order_id, 
              ( SELECT  SUM(op.quantity)
                    FROM  `oc_order_product` op
                    WHERE  op.order_id = o.order_id
                    GROUP BY  op.order_id
              ) AS products, 
              ( SELECT  SUM(ot.value)
                    FROM  `oc_order_total` ot
                    WHERE  ot.order_id = o.order_id
                      AND  ot.code = 'tax'
                    GROUP BY  ot.order_id
              ) AS tax,
              o.total,
              o.date_added
            FROM  `oc_order` o
            WHERE  o.order_status_id > '0'
              AND  DATE(o.date_added) >= '2015-03-01'
              AND  DATE(o.date_added) <= '2016-04-19'
            GROUP BY  o.order_id
      ) tmp
    GROUP BY  WEEK(tmp.date_added)
    ORDER BY  tmp.date_added DESC
    LIMIT  0,60
```

Queries like this make my site very slow. Is there any easy way to convert  this query from sub query to joins.
Here is the output of above query
[image]

Comment: It would be easier to answer your question if you showed some sample data and generated output because we could picture the task better and could even use the sample data to test our approaches.

Comment: I attach the output, please review it

Comment: Well, there is no easy way to do this. You can move the subqueries from the select list to the from clause. This way the subqueries would be run only once. You need to work from inside out and make sure at every single step that the outputs still match the original ones.

Comment: I haven't try as you say till now, but I try to add joins by myself somehow I succeed

SELECT MIN(o.date_added) AS date_start, MAX(o.date_added) AS date_end, COUNT(o.order_id) AS `orders`, SUM(op.quantity) AS products, SUM(ot.value) AS tax, SUM(o.total) AS total FROM `oc_order` o LEFT JOIN `oc_order_product` op ON op.order_id = o.order_id LEFT JOIN `oc_order_total` ot ON ot.order_id = o.order_id AND ot.code = 'tax' WHERE o.order_status_id > '0' AND DATE(o.date_added) >= '2015-03-01' AND DATE(o.date_added) <= '2016-04-19' GROUP BY WEEK(o.date_added) ORDER BY o.date_added DESC LIMIT 0,60

Comment: now the problem is only orders, total shows false result otherwise everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

`WEEK` will have a hiccup around the first of the year -- there will be two partial weeks.

We are now in "week" 16 of 2016.  That corresponds to slightly different days of 2015; did you want them combined?

Because of those hiccups with `WEEK`, you had better change the final `ORDER BY` to `WEEK(tmp.date_added) DESC`

The `FROM ( SELECT ... )` is probably fine.  Is that what you are asking about?

The two `( SELECT SUM ... ) AS ...` are probably optimal, or nearly so.  Is that what you are asking about?

However, you probably do need some indexes:

```
oc_order_total: INDEX(code, order_id) -- in that order
oc_order_product: INDEX(order_id)
```

Change `DATE(o.date_added) >= '2015-03-01'` to `o.date_added >= '2015-03-01'` (etc) so that `INDEX(date_added)` can be used.

If this can be only '1':  `o.order_status_id > '0'`, then change it to `o.order_status_id = 1` so that `INDEX(order_status_id, date_added)` can be used.